# Artifact on playing a audio file on a phone from a Asterisk server

Tags: sip, asterisk, playback

I have an Asterisk SIP server. When I playback an audio file (.ulaw file, compressed using ulaw) I hear a noticeable click (or sound artifact) before the playback begins. This "click" is not in the actual audio file and happens at the start of every Playback command in the ael script. Should I be using a different format, is this a codec issue, how do I resolve this issue?

Here are some of my files:

http://kscserver.com/hello.zip

http://kscserver.com/thankyou.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the file, it's hard to say, but if the first sample of the file starts at some value other than 0, you may get a click (since the output will go from 0 to N in one sample - a broad noise impulse).  If you don't know a sample starts "clean" it can make sense to ramp it in volume-wise, or search the uncompressed data for a zero-crossing and start there.

Comment: Um... ok. Using audacity as an editor, if I add silence to beginning of the file... essential nothing. Will that solve the click?

Comment: No, I just add silence to the begining of the file and the click is still herd on the phone when its played back through asterisk. When I play it back my self, in audacity, I don't here the click.

Comment: I've posted the files in my question. I've zipped them because my web server doesn't understand ulaw files...

Comment: Those are awfully short files - and hello starts with active signal, and it starts *near* (but not at) 0.  It's so short on Linux audacity has trouble playing it.

Comment: Lol, win audacity plays them find.